# How can I oversample OFDM received signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, ofdm

I need to oversample a received signal in OFDM by MATLAB, according to the below diagram, but when I oversample, I finally get the same number of samples however that should be double. !!  The oversampling should be done after receiving the signal, .. as below

[image]

Could you please explain how can I do that resampling in MATLAB? I mean after receiving the signal, which is y = conv(x,h) + n; where x is the transmitted signal and h is the channel, and n is white noise.   so. how can I perform the resampling for y ?

here is what I tried to do :

```
Y_r = resample(R,2,1);   %% R is the received signal
ty = (0:(length(Y_r)-1))*1*Ts/2; 
Y_r_new=exp(-1i*2*pi*Fc*ty).*Y_r;   %the oversampled signal.
```

OK, till now is ok,  but when I run this command, in the first time I put Y_r_new is the oversampled signal, and then change it into Y_r_old which is the original signal, I get an output with same length !!:

```
for isij=1:Numsymbol     %%Numsymbol      is the number of symbols 

    R_D_fil_be=Y_r_new(1,(isij-1)*L_perOFDM+1:isij*L_perOFDM);  %%L_perOFDM is number of carrier multiplied my symbol. 
end
```

Comment: This is a lot to read and digest-- are you able to pull out a much simpler version of your code specific to your problem? Have you tried such a simpler case? I'm not sure you need all this detail to ask your question or find your problem.

Comment: OK , the question, how can I make sampling for received OFDM signal?  I mean according to the above first code, where should I do the sampling ..

Comment: If you are simulating the Tx waveform and the channel, it should be sampled right in the beginning following Nyquist criteria to be at least twice the overall bandwidth of your channel. Typically you sample even higher to allow for a finite filter roll-off.

Comment: OK, thank you .. so according to the code above, where should I perform the sampling, is that right what I am doing  ? I'm talking about sampling when receiving the signal.  I'm not talking about the transmitter..

Comment: Your sampling is defined by Ts, whether it is high enough would depend on your waveform. I wouldn't really be able to figure that all out from reading your code. Could you perhaps add a block diagram to the beginning of your post that shows the spectrum your waveform occupies in Hz, and the sampling rate you are choosing (the actual numbers you are using not variables)?

Comment: the sampling was defined in Ts/2 ..  yes it's higher but Is it true. I modified the question in general and easy way.. is it clear now ?

Comment: Yes much clearer- it sounds like you are asking in general how to upsample a signal in Matlab. If you can add just one line of example code (two at most) showing how you are doing the resampling, I think I should be able to help find your error.

Comment: Added, . could you please help now ..

Comment: The oversampled signal is Y_r. and will be twice as long as R, this line is the correct way to do resampling.  ty is the new time vector  also done correctly. If Y_r is at carrier Fc, then the third line is shifting it to baseband. I do not see any issue with any of this. Not sure why you have a *1* in the second line but that would not cause any errors. There is nothing in the three lines you gave that would cause the oversampled signal to be the same length as the received signal. I suggest that you step through your code one line at a time and observe the length to isolate  you issue.

Comment: OK, thank you.  now I added the part where I get the same length .. Could you re check please

Comment: Well this is adding a value for each symbol so the length will be the number of symbols not number of samples.

Comment: Yes, it's like extracting the number of symbol from the samples .. is that right? so we need another function which extract the number of symbol double the length